# I do not understand foor loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Why inside **for loop** is written **upper + 1** and not just **upper**. If I change **upper+1** with **upper** and run the code, I will have the same result!

**for num in range(lower,**upper + 1**)**

```
# Python program to display all the prime numbers within an interval


lower = int(input("Enter lower range: "))
upper = int(input("Enter upper range: "))

print("Prime numbers between",lower,"and",upper,"are:")

for num in range(lower,upper + 1):
   # prime numbers are greater than 1
   if num > 1:
       for i in range(2,num):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               break
       else:
           print(num)
```

Comment: that's because `upper` is not a prime in your example

Comment: what are you trying to achieve within that loop? As of now, it does nothing and print(num) is never called (?)

Comment: and ** upper + 1**  is a prime in my example? Sorry I don't understan. Can you be a bit more specific, please?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `range(x,y)` stops at `y-1`. For example:

```
for i in range(2,5):
    print(i)
```

will give you:

```
2
3
4
```

So if you want to check `upper` as well, you should add 1, so `upper+1`. Your code returns the same results since `upper` is not prime, so even if upper is checked (with `upper+1` in range), upper will not be printed.

Comment: NP :) And that's also why in your second for loop you have range(2,num) and not range(2,num+1) as you do not want to check num (since num%num will always give you 0)

Comment: :) great. You explain something that I didn't even notice. I will be a great programmer in the near future :D